# How can I see if a timestamp is before now or empty?

Tags: bash

I'm trying to see if a timestamp is expired. Which it would be, if it's before now or empty.

```
exp=1662023095
NOW=$(date +%s)
if [[ -z $exp || (($exp < $NOW)) ]]; then
  echo "Update token..."
else
  echo "Token still valid!"
fi
```

The always echo "Update token...". Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Shows 'still valid' [when running on TIO](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/P7WiwNbQzMzI0MDC1MSSy88/3FZFIyWxJFVBW7VYkys1OSNfQUkFqEqhrFhBBSitxJWZphAdraBbpQAWrqlR0NAAs2zA8pqaCrGx1golGal5XAoKEP2hBWATS/KzU/P09PSUuFJzilPhsiEgYYXiksycHIWyxJzMFEUlrrTM//8B)

Comment: @0stone0 - Sorry, wrong ts. I've updated the question

Comment: So whats the question, `exp` isn;t empty, and `1662023095` is smaller then `1662023667` (now), so the if is triggered as expected?

Comment: If I change exp to 16620230950, it still echo "Update token..."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

found in the `man bash`:

```
When used with [[, the < and > operators sort lexicographically using the current locale.
```

Give this a try (edited following the @user1934428 comment below)

```
if [[ -z $exp ]] || (( exp < NOW )) ; then
...
```

Comment: Upvoted for a nice answer. BTW the expression `if [[ -z $exp ]]` before the edit is still valid. You don't need to wrap variables with double quotes in `[[ .. ]]`.

Comment: I would have expected the arithmetic context to take precedence over the conditional context :/

Comment: the use of ```"{exp}"``` became a reflex, because with other shells and single ```[```, I remember it could cause syntax error when ```exp``` is not defined or empty.

Comment: Inside `[ ... ]` you need quotes of course, but between `[[ .... ]]` you don't, because the latter is a syntactic construct with different parsing rules, while the former just implements `[` as internal command.

Comment: thx @user1934428, answer edited. I learned something today.

Answer (score 2):

The `((...))` doesn't make sense inside `[[...]]`, but you can make it still simpler: If you write it without using `$`, i.e. as

```
if (( exp < NOW ))
then
  ...
fi
```

you don't need to test for an empty `exp` anymore, because `exp` would then be interpreted as if it were zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the exp to old time:
exp=1662023095
which is always less than the current time

```
date "+%s"
```

Sample script:

```
cat "./73566778.sh"
#!/bin/bash
let exp=1662023095
echo "exp:      $(echo "scale=5;$exp / ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)" | bc -q) Years"
let NOW=$(date +%s)
echo "1662023095 seconds is always less than current second $NOW"
echo "NOW:      $(echo "scale=5;$NOW / ( 60 * 60 * 24 * 365)" | bc -q) Years"
echo "if [[ -z $exp ||  $exp -lt  $NOW ]]"
if [[ -z $exp ||  $exp -lt  $NOW ]]
then
        echo "Update token..."
else
        echo "Token still valid!"
fi
```

Output:

```
$ ./73566778.sh
exp:    52.70240 Years
1662023095 seconds is always less than current second 1662025519
NOW:    52.70248 Years
if [[ -z 1662023095 ||  1662023095 -lt  1662025519 ]]
Update token...
```

Hence this will always display:
Update token...

Based on your comment:

> > I'm trying to see if a timestamp is expired.
> > You have to write other script which is having exp data
> > exp=...
> > to update current script.